# IllegalStateException in com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter

Tags: java, android, picasso, illegalstateexception

an exception report appears in the Android Vitals, without an exact trace:

```html
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transformation circle mutated input Bitmap but failed to recycle the original.
  at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter$6.run (BitmapHunter.java:490)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8762)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:604)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

I roughly understand which part of the code is causing the error, here it is:

```html
    public static class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        
            int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

            int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
            int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

            Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
            if (squaredBitmap != source) {
                source.recycle();
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
                    Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);

            float r = size / 2f;

            canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

            squaredBitmap.recycle();
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return "circle";
        }
    }
```

On test devices it is not possible to catch this exception; it occurs only for some users.
If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this exception I would be grateful.

Comment: definitely related to bitmap recycle https://github.com/Pixate/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/BitmapHunter.java